# How to redirect to another template from golang while using jquery form submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, go, beego

I am using form submit jquery to a html page. Data is successfully delivered to my backend beego(golang framework) controller. After running some functions the controller had to decide where to redirect next. But this is been blocked by the jquery. How can I override jquery and redirect using go code?

My script

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: "required"                
        },
        messages: {
            fullname: "Please enter your full name"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    url: '/add_user',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data : $( "#signupForm" ).serialize(),
                    success : function(data) {

                    }
            });
            return false
        }
    });
});
```

My code

```
status := user.AddUserAndCompany(company)
switch status {
case true:
    this.Data["Website"] = "beego.me"
    this.Data["Email"] = "astaxie@gmail.com"
    this.TplName = "index.tpl"
case false:
    this.Data["ErrorMessage"] = "ServerConnectionError"
    this.Layout = "layouts/header_logout.html"
    this.TplName = "templates/registration.html"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "been blocked by the jquery"?

Comment: The page redirect is now only allowed through ajax success block. I need to redirect it from golang code.

Comment: @ArjunAjith Did you solve this issue? I am stuck with the same issue but couldn't find an answer here.

Comment: @ameykpatil I added my solution as an answer. Please go through it. It is not the best way. I was not successful in finding a way to redirect from the back-end itself. But hoping this will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is not a perfect way. But it solved my problem. So I am sharing it. I welcome all suggestions and any other solutions for this problem.

```
switch dbStatus {
    case 0://db Error
        dataToClient = "Server Connection Error"
        this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient)) //Error_msg_1
    case 1://Email already in use
        dataToClient = "EmailError"
        this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient)) //Error_msg_2
    case 2://UserName already in use
        dataToClient = "UserNameError"
        this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient)) //Error_msg_3
    case 3://Everything is fine
        if user.UserType == 0 { //Choosing the url
            dataToClient = "/admin_home" //url_1
            this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient))
        } else {
            dataToClient = "/user_home" //url_2
            this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient))
        }
    }
```

I was not successful in finding out a method to redirect from the back-end. So I coded to choose the url path from the back-end and send it to the front-end with `this.Ctx.ResponseWriter.Write([]byte(dataToClient))`

Now in front-end I did the following:

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
            rules: {
                fullName: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                fullName: "Please enter your full name"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        url: '/add_user',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data : $( "#signupForm" ).serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            //Checking whether the data from back-end is an url or not... 
                            if (data.charAt(0) === '/'){ // if url
                                window.location.href = data;
                            }else{ //else error message
                                document.getElementById('regError').innerHTML = data;
                            }

                        }
                });
                return false
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you redirect to a completely new controller with c.Redirect(redirectURL, 302), where 'c' is your controller ?

I basically use different controllers for "/", "/register" etc.

Comment: This seems like a suggestion/comment rather than an answer.  See [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)